# Howto resolve ranges during release with release plugin

Tags: java, maven, build

We use maven-release-plugin to release our maven components to repository(ies). However, some of these components use ranges on some of our dependencies. We want this because some of the dependencies are released often (Snapshots are not an option)

When we use release plugin the ranges are checked into scm and deployed to our maven repo. This doesn't make any sense since unresolved pom files in the maven repository could (and will) ensure that other build change for one build to another.

We tried using release:prepare-with-pom, but the just makes a new pom file that is committed to scm (release-pom.xml). The original pom with ranges is still deployed to the repo.

As another snag we would like to keep the ranges for the next development release. So our head/trunk should not b resolved.

I have this feeling that we are going about this the wrong way.

Can anyone please help us to solve our problem? If there are other ways to do this we would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: The question is: Why are snapshots no option? In particular for dependencies, cause they exactly intended for such circumstances.

Comment: In this case snapshots is not an option because the modules are not produced by Maven. If using snapshots in general is a good idea for systems that has official testing is beyond the scope of this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have stumbled upon two known maven release plugin bugs. Please see the following bug reports:

- [MRELEASE-618](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-618)
- [MRELEASE-727](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-727)

These are scheduled to be release in version 2.2.3 or 2.3 of maven-release-plugin

**Edit as response to posted comments:**
I agree that it is not obvious why these bugs solves my problem. I'll try to elaborate.

To get the release plugin to use the resolved pom file and deploy it you need to first use release:prepare-with-pom and then release:perform. If you want perform to deploy the resolved pom file you need to set the pomFileName in config to release-pom.xml. If not it deployes the unresolved pom.xml. Deployed pom files with ranges is not a good idea. This is why the 618 is needed.

The 727 is needed because the release-pom.xml is only checked in on the tag. When doing a release:perform your tag is checked out in the target directory. Because og the bug the plugin is looking for the release-pom.xml in the module root directory and comes up empty. This could also possibly go wrong without the pomFileName config, but less likely.

Ranges is generally a bad idea in Maven because it is buggy and because Maven does not by default deploy the resolved pom files. If Maven always deployed resolved pom files ranges would be a good idea.

Comment: It is not obvious why you consider these bugs to be related to your question. Could you expand the answer?

Comment: neither 618 nor 727 are related to the problems described above.

Comment: The above problem arise based on using version ranges in dependencies which is bad practice and with the outcome as described above.